# Spring :: @Transactional not working

Tags: spring, transactions, rollback, spring-transactions, transactional

I am new to Spring and learning the transaction concepts. Unable to get the @Transactional to work.

**Use Case:**
Data insert of Employee and Employee details should rollback when getEmployee() throws RunTimeException. But the rollback is not happening.
I am using Oracle database 11g and spring 4.3.1.RELEASE. Below is the standalone java code am running.

## Code

public static void main( String[] args )
{
    AbstractApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring-bean.xml");
    ctx.registerShutdownHook();

```
Employee emp = new Employee("149518", "Mickey", "Mouse", "15 years", "tennis");

IEmployee empIntfc = (IEmployee)ctx.getBean("empService");
try {
        empIntfc.createEmployee(emp);
        empIntfc.createEmployeeDetails(emp);

        //Below will throw RunTime Exception
        empIntfc.getEmployee(2);

    }catch (Exception e ) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    } finally {
        ctx.close();    
    }
```

}

## EmployeeService.java

```
public class EmployeeService implements IEmployee {

private DataSource dataSource;
private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
    this.dataSource = dataSource;
    jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(this.dataSource);
}
public JdbcTemplate getJdbcTemplate() {
    return jdbcTemplate;
}

@Override
@Transactional
public int createEmployee(Employee emp) {       

    String sql1 = "INSERT INTO TEST_T1(EMP_ID, EMP_FNAME, EMP_LNAME) values   
    (?,?,?)";
    return getJdbcTemplate().update(sql1, emp.getEmpId(), 
    emp.getEmpFirstName(), emp.getEmpLastName());
}

@Override
@Transactional
public int createEmployeeDetails(Employee emp) {

    String sql = "INSERT INTO TEST_T2(EMP_ID, EXP, SKILLS) values (?,?,?)";     
    return getJdbcTemplate().update(sql, emp.getEmpId(), emp.getExp(), 
    emp.getSkills());
}

@Override
@Transactional(readOnly = true, noRollbackFor=RuntimeException.class)
public Employee getEmployee(int empId) {
    throw new RuntimeException("Intentional runtime exception");
}
```

}

## spring-bean.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans">

<context:annotation-config/>
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

<bean id="transactionManager" 
class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
<property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
</bean>
<bean id="dataSource"   
  class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource"  >
  <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"/>
  <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@//xxxx:1521/xxxx"/>
  <property name="username" value="user"/>
  <property name="password" value="user"/>
  </bean> 
  <bean id="empService" class="com.service.EmployeeService">
  <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
  </bean>   
  </beans>
```

Comment: There is already an accepted solution here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9649318/how-can-i-config-to-turn-off-autocommit-in-spring-jdbc

Comment: Your main method is not transactional ... means : entering 'createEmployee' creates a new transaction and commits it, 'createEmployeeDetails' creates a new transaction and commits it ...

Comment: I made the main() method transactional but it did not work.  Took your pointer and wrapped the calls to createEmployee, createEmployeeDetails and getEmployee  in a different class.  Used transactional in the new class method  and it is working now.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main method is not transactional ... means : entering 'createEmployee' creates a new transaction and commits it, 'createEmployeeDetails' creates a new transaction and commits it .